# How can I find out which character code is generated by a given key?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I’m playing around with zsh key mappings. I understand how to create mappings using [the `bindkey` command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle_002c-builtin-commands), but I’m not always sure what the “in string” should be.

For example, I’d like to create a binding for <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>. (I’m using the OS X Terminal application and I have the “Use Option as Meta key” option set.) Is there some command I can invoke and then type <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to see what codes the terminal thinks it’s getting? ([This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245333/getting-character-key-code-mappings-in-ubuntu) on Ask Ubuntu is asking the same thing, but the utilities mentioned in the question and answers seem not to be available on OS X.)

I feel like I should be able to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> in order to get a literal version of this key code, but when I do that I am kicked back to the previous history entry (which is what would happen if I had typed <kbd>↑</kbd> by itself). When I press the <kbd>↓</kbd> key after this I can see that a literal `^[` character has been inserted into the command line but there is nothing after it.

In general, where can I go to find out which codes are generated by a given key or chord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually type `cat` or `cat > /dev/null` (I have an alias for that) to see what appears when I type a key. End with <kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. You may also prefer `cat | hd`. Example with <kbd>↑</kbd>:

```
$ cat | hd
^[[A
00000000  1b 5b 41 0a                                       |.[A.|
00000004
```

Comment: `hd` isn’t available on OS X, but `hexdump` is and does pretty much the same thing. Thanks!